# Wordpress broken after domain name change

Tags: customization, themes, domain

I configured my Wordpress site to use a new domain name. I'm still using the same hosting provider. I have also set-up the old domain to redirect to the new one. Now, the thing I want to achieve is that I want to remove, from the site, all references to the old domain. However, whenever I point my browser to

`new_domain.com/admin`

it gets redirected to

`https://old_domain.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fold_domain.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1`

If I point my browser to

```
old_domain.com/wp-login
```

it thinks that I'm requesting files in a directory named */wp-login* and so gives me "Page not found" error of my site. But if I do

```
old_domain.com/wp-login.php
```

it displays the login form but on submit, I get redirected to

`https://old_domain.com/wp-login.php?wpe-login=true`

And finally, when I login, the url changes to

`https://old_domain.com/wp-admin/`

The other problem is that the theme is completely broken. I've inspected the html source whose `<link>` and `<script>` tags call resources from `old_domain.com/path/to/resource/`

I have tried all the solutions there are out there. Among those are:

1. changing the site and wordpress url from the dashboard settings.
2. applying search and replace all instances of `https://old_domain.com` to `http://new_domain.com` in the database.
3. trying the `define( 'RELOCATE', true );` method; it sets the wordpress url to `http://old_domain.com`
4. in here [When moving a WP site, why does wp-admin redirect to old site?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/155471/when-moving-a-wp-site-why-does-wp-admin-redirect-to-old-site), I found these `define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
   define('WP_SITEURL', WP_HOME . '/');`. Applied them thinking this would fix it as I'm not hard-coding any urls. But these, too, set both the site and wordpress url to `http://old_domain.com`

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I didn't need to move the database or the Wordpress installation around as I didn't change hosting provider. So, as a last resort, would it be a good idea to delete the wordpress installation and reinstall it with all the themes in place?

Comment: See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/157883/how-do-i-change-site-url-to-my-new-domain#answer-157925

Comment: Also, make sure you check in an Incognito window or completely clear your browser cache before trying to reach the new URL. Browsers cache redirects and that may be the final gotcha.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a Search/Replace plugin (I like "Better Search and Replace") to change all instances of 'olddomain' to 'newdomain'.

Then I would look at the wp-options table to ensure the new URL is in there (in two places).  I'd remove any URL-based settings in the wp0config.php file. (I never change those.)

I'd also check the htaccess file in the new site's root folder to ensure that it isn't doing any redirects or rewrites to the old URL.

Then, using a new browser instance (a private one insures caching/cookies aren't an issue), I'd try the new URL. If needed, use the browser Developer Tools (usually F12; or right-click and 'Inspect') and look at the Network tab to ensure all requests are for the new URL