# wp-admin keeps forwarding me to an old url

Tags: migration, domain, hosting, dns

So here's the **general situation**:

- I have been developing an update for an existing website, let's call it domain name "example.com".
- The url I have been using for development is "exampleshop.com".
- I am hosting this project on a droplet in DigitalOcean.
- The example and exampleshop domain names are both registered with a separate registrar

When I browse to example.com it does display the site, which leads me to think I've at least done all the DNS settings right. exampleshop.com displays a 404 error, which also makes sense.

**The issues:**

- When I try to browse to example.com/wp-admin, it automatically redirects me to exampleshop.com/wp-admin.
- Browsing to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) also leads me to exampleshop.com instead, but I have set up a CNAME record for it.
- The SSL certificate (Let's Encrypt) is invalid on example.com because it refers to exampleshop.com

**What I've tried:**

- I've made sure there are no redirects or domain forwards set up on either domain.
- I've tried using the IP leading directly to the DigitalOcean droplet and adding /wp-admin to that
- I've tried using combination of using https versus http and using www. or not, same results.
- I've also tried out the top answer on [this old question I found](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/155471/when-moving-a-wp-site-why-does-wp-admin-redirect-to-old-site) (changed the site and home url directly in the database) and checked it by doing an SQL select for all those values.

I have a few years of experience with launching and hosting websites, but this is only my second wordpress project and I cannot figure out why this is happening. I gave the DNS settings over 24 hours to update, should I just wait another day and hope for the best? Is there some connection between these issues that I'm missing? 
Should things be bleak, I do have a DigitalOcean backup from four days ago and I did migrate my project to a file just before transferring domain names. Should I just wipe my DigitalOcean droplet and restart from a backup?

This is a project I'm building for work where I normally don't get to build websites (which I love to do), so I'd hate to make a bad first impression by struggling with this for so long. Any help is extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem found :) The DigitalOcean droplet was set up for the exampleshop.com domain name, so I needed to go into the apache vhost configuration and change the config files.